# Pattern "Visitor" or a dynamic cast?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I need good advise for my business logic!

I have such classs hierarchy:

```
Parent
- Child1 implements Parent
- Child2 implements Parent
```

Child1 has its own methods and fields as Child2 has its own.

I can write:

```
Parent p = new Child1();
( ( Child1 ) p ).getMethodInParent1

p = new Child2();
( ( Chuld2 ) p ).getMethodInParent2
```

But there are a lot of methods in Child1 and Child2. My main goal is using only one instance of Parent - p. And I want to ask you if it is good aproach of using dynamic cast everywhere in code?

I have read about Visitor pattern. Could it help me in my desire to avoid dynamic cast?

Comment: The code you have provided is way too abstract to understand your actual problem. But yes if you find yourself making casts and depending on actual type then double dispatch is the answer to that. Use Visitor. But you may also tell us actual requirement so that we can help you in a better way.

Comment: OK. My task is creating several entities. F.e. file, service, database wich must implement one parent, f.e. 
interface Mappable

I know how to manage file (create, update, delete), but I don't know about service or database methods. My boss told me that file, service and DB should implement one interface.

So I read about Visitor and it's looking good of using it, cosa it is appropriate for my situation. But now I need add method Search into "file" method set. And it make me trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to ask you if it is good approach of using dynamic cast everywhere in code?

No, it is not. Using casts in general should be regarded as an exception, not as a rule. If your design is based on the need to cast everywhere, you should revisit your design before starting to code.

> Could [the Visitor pattern] help me in my desire to avoid dynamic cast?

Yes, it can. However, you need to remember that introducing a Visitor Pattern in your code significantly increases the complexity of your code, so it needs to be very well justified.

I would try hard unifying the interfaces of `Child1` and `Child2` into the `Parent`, so that a simple polymorphism would be sufficient. If that does not work because the code must behave as virtual with respect to more than one object, I would use the visitor pattern.

Note: Visitor pattern has several limitations. One of them is that your class hierarchy should be reasonably fixed. If you plan to add new `ChildXYZ` implementations to your code, the Visitor pattern will be a liability, not an advantage, because it would make adding new classes harder.

Comment: Yes, I've read about significient of adding new Objects wich should be visited by visitor. But now I have strictly limited number of classes.